# Hook DirectX to make objects in scene transpanent

Tags: c#, directx, hook

I am good at C# programming and I want to know if is possible to make objects from **another** DirectX program about fifty persents tranpanent, so I can see behind them? I will be happy if you provide some working example or link to some tutorial to take me to the right direction.

[image: screenshot]

- I don´t care about DirectX version but it will be great if it work on version 9 and up.
- I don´t know anything about patching DLLs, so it will be great if it only use some C# hooks without dll editing.
- If it isn´t possible with C# it is possible with C++?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible with both C# and C++ Although I prefer c++ for such things, I can recommend C# hook solutions like EasyHooks: https://easyhook.github.io/. With DX9 you might need to hook BeginScene function and apply transparency state, but iut might be too early. You have to do a lot of test. You might also need to modify the object's vertex declarations prior to Present (dx10/11) or EndScene (dx9). IT depends on how the objects are drawn in each application.
You can also check Direct3DHook on GitHub: https://github.com/spazzarama/Direct3DHook

Answer (score 1):

You can look at @VuVirt answer for the hooking portion, but the challenge reside in the translucency portion, here a little list of the things you may have to consider depending on the application you want to hook to:

- Depth testing : If objects are not render back to front, you have to disable depth testing to see them.
- Depth Prepass : If an engine do a pre-pass to fill the depth, you won't be able again to see thought unless you disable that pass fully.
- Translucency need a back to front order to look correct.
- Deferred rendering : Opaque are rendered in multiple render-target and lit in screen space, tweaking the translucency here would be meaningless and pure wrong.
- Occlusion culling : If an application do occlusion culling, the object you wanna see may not even be sent to DirectX.
- Various post process may need to be opaque to copy surface around.
- Way many other obstacles in the way.